# Mongo forcing a log rotation on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, logrotate

I was wondering how I can setup log rotation for a MongoDB on Windows.

I'm only reading it for Linux and Unix based systems in the documentation. Does anyone know how I can set this up?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#forcing-a-log-rotation-with-sigusr1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that MongoDB has it's own logRoation for Windows build in.

Rotate the log file by issuing the logRotate command from the admin database in a mongo shell:

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#rotate-the-log-file

EDIT:

Stennie told in the comment below that you can even do

```
db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

or

```
db.adminCommand('logRotate')
```

Comment: FYI, you can combine that into one command in the `mongo` shell: `db.adminCommand({logRotate:1})` or even simpler: `db.adminCommand('logRotate')`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because log rotation is not a feature of MongoDB but of the Syslog. Windows has completely different object based way of handling this: the [Windows Event Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx).

If MongoDB on Windows writes log files similar to the Linux/Unix version, you'd need a third party solution for handling the log rotation. There seems to be [LogRotateWin](https://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/wiki/LogRotate/).

Comment: Do you know what LogRotateWin does? I'm a programmer and it looks like something easy to create myself without any overhead?

Comment: Well, you could make a program or even a script that checks the age and size of a log file and renames it if it exceeds some limit. Not sure whether MongoDB locks the file or not.